# Linux network interface monitoring

Tags: linux, monitoring

I recently have an issue with my network provider and I'm looking for software that would allow me to create network usage charts.

I need tool that would gather pings to given address, in/out traffic on specified interface, and put it all on some kind of a chart or csv file.

Do you know any good monitoring software that can do that.

I've already tested:

- ntop (kills the drive, bot does it's job);
- bmon (only current usage);
- iptraf-ng (only current usage);
- script that reads ipconfig and ping output (weak - very small accuracy).

Comment: What kind of problems do you have? What do you want to prove? Do you have access to the router? You might need more than one tool (and try `mtr` for pings/traceroute)

Comment: If you have connectivity problems, then I suggest SmokePing http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/

Comment: This linux machine is my router. I want to prove that interface is going down (which I see in logs) and that prior to this bandwidth gets kinky (I don't know how to describe that), another thing is that my provider claims that I have 40Mbps, but in real live I seen maximum 8Mbps so I need a chart with bandwidth and pings during week to make them move 4 letters and do something with it. That's basically my story.

Comment: SmokePing looks great, I'm looking for something like this, that would also monitor bandwidth usage on given interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SeaLion](http://www.sealion.com). You can include any more network monitoring commands and monitor its data with respect to a timeline. It doesn't give charts yet, but you can import the data into a file for sure. I use it for performance monitoring of multiple servers. No harm in trying it since its free!

Answer (score 1):

You can give MTR a try.  I did a bit of googling and came up with this URL for you.   https://library.linode.com/linux-tools/mtr

Comment: I've tested it but it's not something I'm looking for or I can't use it that way (or just don't know how)

Comment: I just replaced my my router with Pfsense http://www.pfsense.org/ Then I installed NTOP on it and it works great!  Easy to set-up and so powerful.  You can even install SNORT on it to turn it into an IDS or Intrusion detection system.